# Android remove space between custom Toolbar and shadow with DrawerLayout

Tags: android

i'm using `Linearlayout` like with android `Toolbar` and i set custom shadow for that, unfortunately after opening `DrawerLayout` i have tiny space between custom toolbar and drawer layout and i can not fix this problem

**CURRENT PROBLEM:**

[image]

**CORRECT VIEW:**

[image]

My custom LinearLayout as an Toolbar with `application_toolbar` name:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:background="#eaeaea"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <pishguy.ir.asrebidree.Widgets.TextViewStyle
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            app:fonttype="mjbeirut"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#737373"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Activity main with drawerLayout and custom toolbar:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- CUSTOM TOOLBAR -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/application_toolbar" />

    <!-- TOOLBAR SHADOW -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_items"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        ...
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Toolbar shadow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="#50949494"
        android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: android:padding="2dp" delete this and try again.because it has something to do with this.

Comment: What if you change the parent layout to be a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout. Then you can nudge the Drawer to be just under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your activity main layout with `DrawerLayout` to the following and you will get the desired result.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- CUSTOM TOOLBAR -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/confirm_toolbar" />


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_items"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

   <!-- TOOLBAR SHADOW -->

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Change the Drawer layout to have a marginTop="-5dp". Basically because it's in a linear layout it will always be under the shadow. the -5dp will nudge it underneath the shadow.</s>

Change the parent layout to be a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout. Then you can nudge the Drawer to be just under it. Make sure you declare the shadow after the Drawer to make it draw last and on top of the Drawer.

Comment: DrawerLayout must be under shadow. with your changes i have that top of shadow

Comment: Edited to reflect new solution which places the drawer underneath the shadow